# Inner div needs float right div that sits on top of other content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Imagine a right panel div that slides out over top of two other divs arranged next to each other (left, right, 100% width).  Its like an info panel that the user can slide out and read, but then dismiss.

But my attempts thus far are producing a panel that wraps underneath the other 2 rather than sitting on top of them.  [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rexdtripod/cpLubcq3/).

How can I get that blue area to sit on top of the red and green?  Note that the red green div is actually, itself, an inner div.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="row">  

              <div class="col-md-12"> 

                <!-- These two div's need to remain side by side -->
                <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color: green; float: left;">
                  Green
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: red; float: right;">
                  Red
                </div>        

                <!-- This div needs to layer on top of the two divs above -->
                <div style="background-color: blue; color: white; float: right;">
                  Blue
                </div>

               </div>
            </div>        

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- This div needs to float to the right of all the content above -->
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: yellow;">
        Yellow
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: why not absolutely position it to the right if it "needs to sit on top"

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `position: static;`, `z-index`, and `float`?

Comment: You forgot to close one of the many `div` elements you have.

Comment: "Why not absolute position it to the right if it needs to sit on top".  Updated fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/rexdtripod/cpLubcq3/1/).  Absolute positioned but blue not floating right.

Comment: Next suggestion (position: static; z-index, and float).  No dice.  Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rexdtripod/cpLubcq3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `position: relative;` on the parent div, then you can adjust the location of the blue div with `position: absolute;` the `top/right/bottom/left` attributes.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpLubcq3/4/)
(I moved all your css to classes so you could better see what was going on.)

Comment: Ahhh...  I missed the top right deal.  Thanks much.